# blazor drop down menu doesn't push the rest of items down

Tags: drop-down-menu, blazor, sidebar

im creating an app in blazor the drop down works but it doesnt push the rest of items down how do i fix this? this is my code

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src="/img/Boxplosive-logo.png" class="logoimg" /></a>
    <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>


<div class="@NavMenuCssClass nav-scrollable" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="index">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Dashboard
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="promotion" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true" href="#"></span> Create
            </NavLink>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
                <NavLink><a class="dropdown-item" href="promotion">Promotion</a></NavLink>
                <NavLink><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Loyalty</a></NavLink>
                <NavLink><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">News Article</a></NavLink>
            </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="publish">
                <span class="oi oi-cloud-upload" aria-hidden="true"></span> Publish
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="analyse">
                <span class="oi oi-graph" aria-hidden="true"></span> Analyse
            </NavLink>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="managment">
                <span class="oi oi-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> Managment
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="configuration">
                <span class="oi oi-list" aria-hidden="true"></span> Configuration
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <nav class="sidebar-footer">

        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
                <span class="oi oi-person" aria-hidden="true"></span> Admin
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="help">
                <span class="oi oi-question-mark" aria-hidden="true"></span> Help
            </NavLink>
            <button class="logoutbtn">Logout</button>
        </div>

    </nav>
</div>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
    private bool expandSubNav;

}
```

i want he drop down the push the other items down when i click on it i tried other code that did push the other items down but it wouldn't indicate what page i am on, i want to keep both functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from this and then customize using css classes and styles.

```
<div class="nav-item px-3">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" @onclick="ToggleSubNavMenu" @onclick:preventDefault>
        <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Create
    </a>  
    @if (expandSubNav)
    {
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="promotion">
            <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Promotion
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="loyalty">
            <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Loyalty
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink class="nav-link" href="newsarticle">
            <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> News Article
        </NavLink>
    }
</div>

@code {
    private bool expandSubNav = false;

    private void ToggleSubNavMenu()
    {
        expandSubNav = !expandSubNav;
    }
}
```